# The special theory of relativity angle contradiction

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

[image]

I always see this picture for proof of the  time relation  between frames that moves relatively constant speed in  the special theory of relativity.

The time for the observer who is in the box which travel at constant speed $V$.

$$ t'=\frac{h}{c} \tag 1$$

The time for observer who is outside of the box.

$$ t=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}{c} \tag 2$$

$$ t=\frac{x}{V} \tag 3$$
and the time relation between observers is
$$ t'=t \sqrt {1-\frac{V^2}{c^2}} \tag 4$$
Everything is Ok till here.

According to outside observer, the person who adjusts the laser gun (yellow drawn in picture) angle in the box must change the angle ($\alpha$) as shown in right side of the picture if the light is not affected from the speed of the box as the special theory of relativity claims. 
However, According to inside observer who adjust the laser angle, the angle should be exactly $90^0$  because the inside observer will not understand that the box moves.

How does the special theory of relativity explain this dilemma?

(Please assume that the sensor on top is very small and the laser has very focused slim light beam and the box is quite speedy otherwise the angle always would be very near $90^0$ and the angle cannot be detected for low speeds. )

Comment: There isn't an adjustment to be made or an angle to be changed, in the box you shoot it at 90° degrees, the observer outside the box sees a different angle, that's an effect called aberration of light. Nothing is in contrast with relativity, the speed of light is not affected by the motion of the box. You may say that its components change, that's true, but its speed is always c.

Comment: @Runlikehell  Will the outside observer see  that the laser equipment angle changed to $\alpha$ although the inside observer claims that no need to change from $90^0$? Is not it absurd? Because when the box stopped the events will not be not much . If the laser equipment  angle is also $90^0$ for outside observer , the light should be clever to know the direction of the box. It means there should be an ether as the same  we observe this  kind of actions in  the river. I wonder how we eliminate this dilemma.

Comment: Yes I think the observers see different angles. Because of Lorentz contraction you see an object in motion relative to you rotated, that's an apparent rotation known as [Terrell rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrell_rotation).  But the guy inside doesn't make any adjustment, if he did change the angle the light beam wouldn't hit the detector in his own reference frame.

Comment: Observer who is at rest will see photon coming at oblique angle. In this case the source, the photon and the sensor on the top always have the same x coordinate. Terrell rotation is purely optical illusion. If the sphere is semi - transparent and a measuring rod is placed inside the sphere, on a picture we will see that sphere is rotated and measuring rod is contracted.

Comment: Of course it is only an apparent rotation, plus he would see the rod tilted with its head pointing in the direction opposite to the one of the motion. But the OP asked in comments if the two observers saw different angles, that's why I advocated the rotation, even if it is an apparent rotation, the observer at rest sees another angle.

Comment: @Runlikehell If it is like optical illusion to rotate $\alpha$ for outside observer but $90^0$ for inside observer , what can happen when we put one more laser gun next to sensor and one more sensor next to current laser gun? We should see opposite $\alpha$  rotate for second sensor on floor.  Thus, Apparent rotation is not sense if we think in this way. What do you think about this?

Comment: @Mathlover apparent rotation is something that happens, we cannot avoid it cause of the finitness of the speed of light. It doesn't answer your question, I was just pointing it out the fact that the two observer can see different angles which was something that it seemed that bothered me. The rod is vertical, it's just the observer at rest that sees it it rotated ( he sees it tilted with its head pointing in the direction opposite to the one of the motion). This is not an answer to your question, I just wanted to make you see the fact that they can observe different angles.

Comment: @Mathlover in an ideal situations which is having the chance to know the position of the extreme points of the rod at the {\bf exact same time} (That is not possible in practical aspects) the observer at rest sees the rod vertical and not tilted, that's why you can still consider it vertical like the other user said, so in this sense again, the apparent rotation is not relevant to your question, it was just to clarify the possibility of seeing different angles which  you said it didn't make sense.

Comment: A laser is not a magic black box that emits light in the direction that it is pointed.  To answer this question, you have to understand ***how*** a laser works.

Answer (score 5):

The laser gun is not rotated for the outside observer. It is still at 90 degrees. Just imagine that some laser light leaks out of the back of the laser gun, then you would have **two different** angles that the laser gun would have to rotate in ....

The laser gun is still at 90 degrees relative to the box but it sends out light under an angle because of **non-simultaneity**. The phase over the surface of its output is not constant in the x-direction due to non-simultaneity. Such a varying phase is also how phased array radars can send out a beam under an angle. See the image below (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phased_array)

[image]

It sends out the beam under an angle and the wavefront of the laser beam also rotates (The wave front should always be in the direction of the propagation). See the middle image below for the Lorentz transformed frame.

The image at the left depicts a photon bouncing up and down in the box for the observer inside the box. The middle image shows the photon bouncing up and down as seen by the observer outside the moving box.

[image]

Without non-simultaneity, as in the "Mansoury-Sexl" transform in the image on the right, the wavefront would not rotate.

The image below explains the effect. The term $~t' =\gamma(t-\beta x)~$ shows  how $t'$ depends on x. Looking at the image below: At the left side time has progressed further and thus the phase of the wave front has progressed further. At the right side it's the opposite. The net effect is that the wavefront rotates.

[image]

For more see the relevant chapter of my book here: http://www.physics-quest.org/Book_Chapter_Non_Simultaneity.pdf

Comment: Do you claim that the laser gun angle is $90^0$ for outside observer too? If so, you think that the light has the same effect as a river affects an object for outside observer. Sorry but I did not understand with your explanations how  the light knows the direction of the box and the speed of the box and goes to sensor's direction on top if the angle of laser gun is $90^0$?

Comment: Yes the laser gun angle is 90 degrees for the outside observer as well off course. Only imagine that some laser light leaks out of the back of the laser gun. then you would have two different angles that the laser gun would have to rotate in. Non simultaneity  has nothing to do with a 'River' Maybe you could first try to understand the 'phased array' example first and then understand why non-simultaneity causes the phase to vary over the surface of the laser gun output.

Comment: Great explanation. Just one comment: don't lasers work more like the "bouncing photon clock" than like phased array radars?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the outside observer the laser gun should not be tilted. It will be directed straight up too. The source and photon will move in positive x direction with the same velocity and will always have the same x coordinate. Please look at this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-AAC4pemDI

In the first episode moving source (a lamp) launches a photon. Both photon and the lamp always have the same X coordinate. Then a small tube appears on the top of the lamp. This tube imitates laser pointer, which always directed at right angle to direction of motion.

I think I understand what confuses you. You think that for moving observer velocity of light in different directions is the same. Not quite. Imagine two observers A and B, who move relatively to each other. Let A conduct observations from his reference frame K. A admits, that velocity of light is c in his frame K. But, if observer B, who moves in this frame K flashes a lamp, observer A will see, that light recedes from B with different velocities in different directions.

However, if B wants to conduct measurements, he introduces his own frame K’ and admits that velocity of light in different directions is c. But now B will see, that if A flashes a lamp, light recedes from A with different velocities.

In Special Relativity observer NEVER admits state of his own motion. Observer is always at rest in his own rest frame.

Thus, in Special Relativity every observer covers “mutual for all observers” space by his own reference frame. This reference frame implies that there is an Einstein – synchronized clock in each point of space. Special Relativity is the change of frames. Observers never use one mutual one, but each has his own.

In the same frame moving observer sees, that clock of observer at rest runs faster, not slower. If he wants to measure time dilation, he has to change reference frame and introduce his own one.

Please compare how many ticks moving clock does and how many any synchronized one. Moving clock makes less ticks that one at rest. That means, from the point of view of a moving clock time in reference frame tick faster.  You will see, that once moving clock turns into one at “rest” so as to see time dilation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#/media/File:Time_dilation02.gif

Comment: This action that you defined  is the same effect as we throw a rock to upside in a train. The rock which we throw to upside always goes as you defined in your answer.  If the light is not affected by the speed of box and the angle of gun is $90^0$ for outside observer, how the light can go in the same speed with box in x direction .  The principle you defined  brakes the special theory ."... light is always propagated in empty space with a definite velocity [speed] c which is independent of the state of motion of the emitting body"  Best Regards

Comment: Light propagates with velocity c in observer's frame.  But  "outside observer" will see, that beam of light recedes from source with velocity lesser than c.  For outside observer beam moves on the hypotenuse,  but it's components by triangle legs less than c. For example, please look at http://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm, starting from "  Another interesting aspect of aberration is illustrated by considering two separate light sources S1 and S2, and two momentarily coincident observers A and B as shown below "

Comment: I have added some my reflections into the answer

Comment: I understand  your point of view ,The gift in end explains very well. I know If the laser gun angle is $90^0$  for outside observer and If we wants that the laser light hits sensor, X direction speed must be $V$ in your approach.  The problem is in this idea: To have a constant the speed of light need to decrease the speed that goes to upside way ( $V_y^2=c^2-V^2$). How does the light know the speed of the box and decrease upside speed ($V_y$) to adjust and to get the total speed is $c$ if special relativity claims that the light is independent of the state of the motion of the emitting body.

Comment: I think that the particle approach of photon has problem in here if the special relativity is true.

Comment: Moving observer wants to hit a target and keeps his tube straight up. The faster he moves the further from the target he has to launch a photon and the more oblique angle will be in target's reference frame. It is not much different from ping pong when players move relatively, difference is relativistic aberration formula for the angles of emission and reception.  http://relativistic-transverse-doppler-effect.com/, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hnphFr2Iai4